# FULL JOIN : Select the key I join on

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here's the table I start with

```
CMS   |   defect_status 
________________________
1     |   true
2     |   false
3     |   true
3     |   false
```

and here's what I want

```
   CMS    |      true_defects    |   false_defects
   1      |      1               |   0
   2      |      0               |   1
   3      |      1               |   1
```

So here's my code

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    false_table.CMS, 
    true_table.true_defects,
    false_table.false_defects

FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        CMS,
        COUNT(*) AS true_defects 
    FROM data_table
    WHERE defect_status = 'true'
    GROUP BY CMS 
) as true_table

FULL JOIN(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        CMS,
        COUNT(*) AS false_defects 
    FROM data_table
    WHERE defect_status = 'false'
    GROUP BY CMS 
) as false_table
ON true_table.CMS = false_table.CMS
```

I would like to select all CMS, those in "false_table" and "true_table". 
If I select "false_table.CMS" (as in the code above), here's what I get :

```
CMS    |      true_defects    |   false_defects
2      |      0               |   1
3      |      1               |   1
```

CMS "1" has disappeared simply because it's not in the column false_table.CMS

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using a case statement instead and sum the results? Using a full join here is a bit strange.

Comment: According to the duplicate question, full join isn't possible in mysql. How are you getting results? Are you sure you're using mysql?

Comment: @Andrew how would you go about it with a CASE statement ?

Comment: @HoneyBadger you're right I removed the mysql tag

Comment: If this is not mysql, can you tag this with the correct database, and we can attempt to get it re-opened.

Comment: So which DBMS **are** you using?

Comment: I think it is not the duplicate one, it is totally different one.Maybe tag added wrongly

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name IT's actually postgressql, just tagged it

Comment: @Jdoe: You can achieve it by case and group by : demo link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8478d/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by simple `case` and `group by`  as below:

```
SELECT t1.CMS
    ,sum(CASE defect_status
            WHEN true
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS true_status
    ,sum(CASE defect_status
            WHEN false
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS false_status
FROM Table1 AS t1
GROUP BY CMS
```

Demo link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8478d/1